# How to edit G-code created in Cura to begin printing at a specified layer height?

Tags: print-quality, 3d-models

I have an issue with implementing a G-code to print a large 3D object using the Creality CR-10 printer. The print went well for over 30 hours but the filament broke off during the print and stopped at a height of around 172 mm of a total height of 256 mm. 1753 layers total , stopped at layer 1170.

I want to restart the print so the extruder begins printing at a height of 172 mm rather that from the start.

I have tried several sites online and had removed the previous 1169 layers and also changed the start position of the extruder to the code below:

```
G1 X20 Y20 Z385; Center extruder above bed
```

The problem I have is that when I start the print, the extruder moves to the middle of the plate and begins moving upwards but I need the extruder to stay near the edge of the build plate and move upwards past 172 mm and *then* begin printing as it would have for layer 1169 and continue the print. At the moment the extruder moves upwards and towards the middle of the plate and will impact with the existing printed material (see picture attached) and this stops it from correctly positioning.

[image: Existing printed material on build plate]

Can anyone help with the start code for the G-code that I could use ? I just need the x,y,z to home and then for the extruder to stay near the edge of the build plate but move past 172 mm in the z direction before then beginning to print. Any advice would really be appreciated , first question on this platform so apologies if the detail isn't there. If you need anything more please don't hesitate to get in touch.

Comment: Well, how about `g1 x0 y0 z385 ` ?  And make sure there are no other move commands, including any "initialization" macros.

Comment: I have recovered a print from a similar issue before by re-slicing what I needed to print on the already printed object and then manually adjusting the z home position so the printer thought it was at zero and removing the z homing g-code from the start of the g-code file. 
But this could cause some machines to damage them self.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is a little complicated since nozzle height could collides with the part if the line 1169 has had started to be printed (part of the line), so the overlap will be the main problem, however adding the initial parameters to heat the extruder and getting the `X0` and `Y0` with `G1 X0 y0 Z385` I recommend to **increase Z by 3 or 5 mm**, so the extruder will travel from a higher position **to avoid the crash going for example, from `Z390` to `Z385`**.

Comment: Hey Fernando thanks for the advice I got it to work last night and start printing from where it left off but unfortunately I messed with the level of the bed so it was out by a couple of mm.

Comment: @CBable Oh, that´s corrrect. if the printer needs bed leveling the problem can be a total disaster; I forget to add this comment. I tried this several times and trying to start printing one layer above is perfect.